# Error using https with self signing certificate from different IP

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, express, ssl

I have converted my `nodejs` server to use `https` by doing this

```
const https = require('https');
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-access-token');
  next();
});
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(port)
  .on('error', error => {
    logger.error(error);
  })
  .on('listening', () => {
    logger.info(`Express listening on ${port}`);
  });
```

Now when I serve html files with jquery, the API calls work fine, when I use `postman` I need to disable `ssl certificate validation` from `settings --> general` and it works, now I am trying to deploy an `angular 6` app on my `localhost` while the server is on azure at a certain IP but I am getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. I guess if postman works by removing the validation option, is there something similar I need to do for this in the angular code?

Currently APIs are on `https://137.xxx.xx.xx:8000/api/v0/......`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'cors' package as follows

```
$npm i -S cors

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({origin:"http//:localhost:3000"}));
```

Change origin as you need it depending which origin you will use to make your calls.

Comment: The angular UI and the nodejs server are on two different computers, one is my laptop, other is an azure server.

Comment: you need to add the cors package to your server side, it helps you avoid cors related issues. Just put in the origin value the url from where you are making the request, in your case "http://localhost:3000 if your angular front end is on your laptop just look after the port you angular app is listening.

Comment: Well If I put localhost:3000 in the server, it will be for the APIs called from within the same IP. My product is on a different laptop altogether. The UI is being served from a local server by my company, the server from azure

Comment: You're right, my bad, use in this case '*' instead so you could get calls from anywhere including the local host.

Comment: In my code I am already using `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`. Shouldn't this work? Either way I will check this answer and let you know if it works.